# Update the values of particular key in json returned array of dictionary in SWIFT

Tags: json, dictionary, swift3, nsarray

I am getting some response in JSON data array of dictionary format. I need to update the value for particular keys which are 'TotalValue' and 'IndexValue' (making their values rounded of to 2 decimal places).

```
[
  {
    "Id" : 2010,
    "TotalValue" : 100.91478,
    "IndexValue" : 100.75859,
    "Date" : "7\/9\/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "Compare" : "ABC"
  },
  {
    "Id" : 2010,
    "TotalValue" : 99.914788865745123,
    "IndexValue" : 100.86935289185379,
    "Date" : "7\/10\/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "Compare" : "ABC"
  }
]
```

while I am trying to convert it into NSDictionary, taking each each dictionary out in loops it's giving me error related to typecasting. Please suggest some solution

Comment: Here Your Data is in NSArray formate get as NSArray and inside Array, Particular Object gets as NSDisctionary and then Update Value.

Comment: Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift. The dictionaries are `[String:Any]` and you have to cast both `...Value` types to `Double`

Comment: how to update a particular value from the dictionary?